# Determine if the array has negative numbers and change them to zero

Tags: php, arrays

I have wrote this code:

```
$final = array(
    ($data[0] - $data[1]),
    ($data[1] - $data[2]), 
    ($data[2] - $data[3]),
    ($data[3] - $data[4]),
    ($data[4] - $data[5]), 
    ($data[5] - $data[6]) 
);
```

Some of them will return negative numbers (`-13`,`-42` etc...), how to change the negative ones to `0`?

By the way the think i do after is:

```
$data_string = join(",", $final);
```

**Example:** I need to convert it like in the following:

```
1,3,-14,53,23,-15 => 1,3,0,53,23,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Hakre's compact answer. However, if you have a more complex requirement, you can use a function:

```
<?php

$data = array(11,54,25,6,234,9,1);

function getZeroResult($one, $two) {
    $result = $one - $two;
    $result = $result < 0 ? 0 : $result;

    return $result;
}

$final = array(
    getZeroResult($data[0], $data[1]),
    getZeroResult($data[1], $data[2]), 
    getZeroResult($data[2], $data[3]),
    getZeroResult($data[3], $data[4]),
    getZeroResult($data[4], $data[5]), 
    getZeroResult($data[5], $data[6]) 
);

print_r($final);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/viGBYj4f (With an `echo` to show the `$result` before test.)

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 29
    [2] => 19
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 225
    [5] => 8
)
```

Note, you could also just return the ternary:

```
function getZeroResult($one, $two) {
    $result = $one - $two;
    return $result < 0 ? 0 : $result;
}
```

As well as using it in a loop:

```
<?php

$data = array(11,54,25,6,234,9,1);

function getZeroResult($one, $two) {
    $result = $one - $two;
    echo "$one - $two = $result\n";
    return $result < 0 ? 0 : $result;
}

$c_data = count($data)-1;
$final = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $c_data; $i++) {
    $final[] = getZeroResult($data[$i], $data[$i+1]);
}

print_r($final);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/31WCbpNr

Comment: thanks, clean and understandable! Just one problem with this, I'm using it all inside of a `while` loop and it throws an error for the second time: `Cannot redeclare getZeroResult() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\:40) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ on line 40`

Comment: Don't declare a function in a `while`, `foreach` or `for` loop. Declare it in the global scope (not in any other construct).

Comment: Note, that should have said `function`, not `variable`.

Comment: @Ricardo - Also note that when you edit a comment, SO doesn't notify me that you edited it. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

You can map that:

```
$zeroed = array_map(function($v) {return max(0, $v);}, $final);
```

Will set all numbers lower than 0 to 0.

See [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`max`](http://php.net/max).

Additionally, you can save you some more handwriting with `$data`:

```
$final = array_reduce($data, function($v, $w)
{
    static $last;
    if (null !== $last) $v[] = max(0, $last - $w);
    $last = $w;
    return $v;
}, array());

$data_string = join(",", $final);
```

See [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce).

**Edit:** A foreach loop might be easier to follow, I added some comments as well:

```
// go through all values of data and substract them from each other,
// negative values turned into 0:
$last = NULL; // at first, we don't have a value
$final = array(); // the final array starts empty
foreach($data as $current)
{
    $isFirst = $last === NULL; // is this the first value?
    $notFirst = !$isFirst;

    if ($notFirst)
    {
        $substraction = $last - $current;
        $zeroed = max(0, $substraction);
        $final[] = $zeroed;        
    }
    $last = $current; // set last value
}
```

And here is the [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/q5TFxP).

Comment: Looks like the thing i was looking for but seems like you forgot a letter or two there, i will look out for the error now.

Comment: I just typed it in, the code is untested, let me check. - and the second example is wrong, this needs another mapping - fixed now.

Comment: oh my gosh i think your answer is more for pro's like you cause i can't really understand what's going on here, guess ill read the doc's now.

Comment: you want a loop? - I'll turn the second example into one quickly - done.

Answer (score 2):

Am guessing this is homework. If so please mark it as such.

Hints:

- use a loop instead of hardwired array references.
- use an if-statement to check for negative values and switch their sign.
- your use of *join* is correct

Comment: Basically i like to learn while working (no it's not a homework) I'm just building some scripts to gain experience. as for the answer - I was thinking about the if-statement and i can do that but I'm wondering if there is some "clean" way to do that. and about the loop, how can i do that?