# PHP combining two nearest words in a string

Tags: php, string, algorithm, substring

I need php code for combining two nearest words in a string

eg : " I need to be shorter for sure by a lot"

I need ,need to ,to be, be shortner,shorter for,for sure,sure by,by a,a lot

Any ideas? Really don't know any way to approach this

Comment: This is not 'give me the code' site.

Comment: yo want to get rid of duplicates and only show one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if the array has negative numbers and change them to zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023517/determine-if-the-array-has-negative-numbers-and-change-them-to-zero)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are new, I'll create some code for you, but you should try it for yourself first from now on.

```
function pairwise_sentence($sentence)
{
    $pairs = array();
    $words = explode(' ', $sentence);

    for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($words); $i++)
        $pairs[] = $words[$i - 1] . ' ' . $words[$i];

    return implode(',', $pairs);
}
```

This will generate what you describe. You could remove the `implode` function and just return the pairs if you need an array with word-pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "I need to be shorter for sure by a lot";

$words = explode(" ", $string);
$loop_count = count($words) - 1;

for ($i=0; i<$loop_count; $i++) {
    // compare $words[$i] and $words[$i+1]
}

?>
```